# Local Git Repo to TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

Have VS 2015 Update 2 and TFS 2015 Update 2 installed and working.

I created a solution and must have clicked a local Git repo for it.  Now I want to Right Click Solution and Add to Source Control, but that menu option is missing.  How can I fix this and check in the solution to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to close the solution first
2. Navigate to the folder where your project is stored
3. delete .git hidden folder
4. open solution
5. make sure your source control provider is selected as TFS (under options)
6. right click solution, add to source control.

Note depending on where the project was originally created, you may want to move the folder to your normal workspace prior to doing the above, to help make sure it gets added to the correct collection

Comment: That worked (had to do it twite before it took), but you'd think that you could check a Local Git Repo into a TFS store.

Comment: it works fine for me. Thank you for the easy solution.